# why is password hash not being saved with user object in mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, frontend, backend

I have a route for creating user but the passwaord hash defined as part of the user schema is not saved in mongodb so it is impossible for me to authenticate. Can soneone please help me look at what am doing wrong?

Userschema and transform method

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  name: String,
  passwordHash: String,
  blogs: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Blog',
    },
  ],
});

userSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString();
    delete returnedObject._id;
    delete returnedObject.__v;
    delete returnedObject.passwordHash;
  },
});
```

```
ROUTE
userRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  const body = request.body;

  const saltRound = 10;
  const passwordHarsh = await bcrypt.hash(body.password, saltRound);
  console.log(passwordHarsh);

  const user = new User({
    username: body.username,
    name: body.name,
    passwordHarsh
  });

  console.log(user, 'USER');
  const savedUser = await user.save();

  response.status(201).json(savedUser);
});
```

However, the password Hash is not saved as part of the object. I have tried everything

Comment: `passwordHarsh` in your code != `passwordHash` in your schema

Comment: @mickl Literally harsh.

Comment: thanks so much guys. now it works